# Razor, Resharper, and Less on WebStorm

Tags: .net, razor, resharper, webstorm

Is it possible to work with ReSharper, Less and Razor using Jetbrains Webstorm? Can someone point me to specific plug-ins i might need?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.
ReSharper only works with Visual Studio. Webstorm doesn't support C# and Razor. But of course, you can use Visual Studio + ReSharper for C# and Razor and use Webstorm for JavaScript and CSS in the same project.

Comment: I´m planning to do it like you suggest. I see that both tools, VS and WS create their own project files, I´m wondering is something to be aware of that may cause problems when editing same file with both IDES?

Comment: @Juan Of course you cannot edit the same file in both IDEs, you should edit JS and CSS only in WS, and C# and Razor only in VS. I guess you mean viewing in one IDE and editing in other. I don't know any gotchas, sorry. It's better to ask on some WebStorm forum.